# Buttons in X-Wing cockpit - what do they do? (Vr experience)

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I was surprised that i could not find references online.

Anyway the buttons in the cockpit can be pushed - most seem to do nothing but lighting up.  But some seem to trigger that I don't know how to achieve otherwise (on PS4).

Does anyone know what they do?

So far I have identified:

- two large buttons left of monitor: upper triggers shield, lower s-foils between battle and fligth
- right of the monitors a single button next to schematics changes laser configuration (4 simlutanuous, two at a time, one per shot)
- about 90° to the right, group of two buttons - the one with label triggers the "trench run scope"
- the one furthest back on the left makes R4 whistle